# What type of design pattern is the AngularJS $scope object?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, design-patterns, scope

I'm new to SO and have been learning and working with JavaScript and AngularJS for about 3 months, so super super new to the field. I'm in the process of going deeper into JS and am studying Design Patterns, so a question popped up in my head -> What type of design pattern is the $scope object?

I have done a fair bit of reading but other than the obvious -> being part of the MVC architecture of AnguarJS, I can't imagine anything more specific.

I'm looking forward to hearing some more experienced developers's answers on this.

Answer (score 3):

The $scope is a two-way data binding object used as part of the MVC pattern in AngularJS. In itself, it is not a design pattern.

The $scope in an AngularJS is a built-in object, which contains application data and methods. You can create properties to a $scope object inside a controller function and assign a value or function to it.

The $scope is glue between a controller and view (HTML). It transfers data from the controller to view and vice-versa.

[AngularJS Docs scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope)

Comment: Is the name $scope intended to mimic a viewing device, such as a periscope?  Or is it intended to reference 'scope' in the sense of a variable's scope in computer science?  Or neither (it certainly isn't named after the mouthwash brand) ...

Comment: Scope is an object that refers to the application model. Each AngularJS application has exactly one root scope, but may have any number of child scopes. I guess the name 'Scope' is intended to reference to the application context scope your in.

Comment: Thanks @BjarneGerhardt-Pedersen for the answer. That's true, the $scope object has very unique qualities, which is what made me wonder where it could be classified in the Design Pattern categorisation scheme. Of course, not everything needs to be put in boxes, thanks again for your thoughts.